# The constructor HashSet<Integer>(int[]) is undefined

Tags: java, set

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.awt.*;

public class hash {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] paco = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5 };  //an array with duplicate items for the set
        Arrays.asList(paco);

        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>(paco);  

    }

}
```

this is a simple exercise to get used to creating hashSets from lists. 
First I made an array, then converted it to a list, after that attempted to convert it to a HashSet, however I get the following error:
*The constructor HashSet(int[]) is undefined*

Comment: And what is abnormal about this ? There is indeed no such constructor in the javadoc.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of creating an array and then creating a list, create the list directly from your values:

```
List<Integer> paco = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5);
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>(paco);
```

The other problem was that you weren't saving the return value of `Arrays.asList` anywhere.

If you just try to do `Arrays.asList(paco)` on an `int[]`, it will return a `List<int[]>` (a list of int arrays) with a single element. That cannot be used to initialize a set.

If you really want to also have an array of the values in addition to the set, you can declare them as `Integer` rather than `int`, which will cause them to be boxed and then `Arrays.asList` will create a `List<Integer>` from them, instead of a `List<int[]>`:

```
Integer[] paco = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5 };
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(paco));
```

If you need to convert an `int[]` into an `Integer[]` it can be done with [ArrayUtils from Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) in the following way:

```
Integer[] boxedArray = ArrayUtils.toObject(primitiveArray);
```

Thanks to Tomek for the tip.

Comment: +1 for your answer.Do you know of an easy way to convert array of primitive to Array of Objects for the corresponding Wrapper Object

Comment: Integer[] newArray = ArrayUtils.toObject(oldArray); from http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/